# @media only screen and [não funciona!]

Tags: css

tudo bem? Bom, venho até vocês através deste tópico fazer-lhes a seguinte pergunta:

Tenho um site do qual estou desenvolvendo o processo de CSS do mesmo. E claro, para mexer nisso, decidi usar o método do [@media only screen and] ele funciona em absolutamente **quase** tudo, isso porque, tive um problema do qual não consigo solucionar.

Esse código:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px){.module .content .items .item {
width: calc(100%/ 3);
padding: 5px;}
```

O padrão dele (em tela de Desktop):

```
.module .content .items .item {
width: calc(100%/ 5);
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 1px;
position: relative;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

A diferença entre os dois, é o padding e o width. Pois, em um quando a tela é Desktop, ele mostra (100% / 5) ou seja, 5 itens por fileira, já em mobile, ele **deveria** mostrar (100% / 3) ou seja, 3 itens por fileira. Porém, não sei porque cargas d'água ele não ativa o modo @media only screen dessas classes no mobile.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está faltando fechar as chaves, `}`, do `@media`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consegui resolver fazendo o seguinte:

Eu tenho 2 arquivos css, um para um display **Desktop** e outro para **Mobile**, apenas implementei o mesmo código para o .css do **Desktop** e funcionou! ;)

Coloquei o mesmo código do mobile nele:

.module .content .items .item {
    width: calc(100%/3);
    padding: 5px;
}

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda ♥